# Use getPositionStream to add location indicator Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a HERE map with various functionality operating fine

I have a `location indicator` that currently operates `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();` which works fine, taking the `lat,long` and `heading` to place indicator.

I want it to update with users location from device.

I need to use `Geolocator.getPositionStream` to achieve this but after trying the implementation example online I'm stuck as it has different requirements to Current Position and the code won't work

Here is the LocationIndicator method, set to `getRandom`

```
void _addLocationIndicator(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, LocationIndicatorIndicatorStyle indicatorStyle) {
  LocationIndicator locationIndicator = LocationIndicator();
  locationIndicator.locationIndicatorStyle = indicatorStyle;


  Location location = Location.withCoordinates(geoCoordinates);
  location.time = DateTime.now();
  location.bearingInDegrees = _getRandom(0, 360);

  locationIndicator.updateLocation(location);


  _hereMapController.addLifecycleListener(locationIndicator);
}
```

This is the given code for Stream

```
final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
  accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  distanceFilter: 100,
);
StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
    (Position position) {
        print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + position.longitude.toString());
    });
```

This is the Current Location example which I have used and it works fine for current location

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.
///
/// When the location services are not enabled or permissions
/// are denied the `Future` will return an error.
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
  
  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  } 

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

Thanks